# Re-write $.ajax request as JavaScript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get better at writing my code in JavaScript and not using jQuery. I've got an $.ajax request which i'm trying to rewrite as an XMLHttpRequest, but getting errors "POST http://localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)".

The jQuery version works fine, but the JS version doesn't. I get the same error from the jQuery version if I remove `data: filter.serialize(),` so I feel the issue lies here as there isn't an equivalent version in the JS request, but i'm unsure how to write/add this into it.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great : )

```js
/** Working jQuery filter */
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#filter").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var filter = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: WP.ajax,
      data: filter.serialize(),
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        $("#response").append("Loading...");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#response").html(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```js
/** NOT working JS filter */
var af = new XMLHttpRequest();
document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("filter").value = this.value;
  af.onload = function() {
    if (af.status === 200) {
      document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = af.responseText;
      console.log(af.responseText);
    }
  };
  af.open("POST", WP.ajax);
  af.send();
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. We need more information than 'not working' in order to help you debug something.

Comment: Note you need to create a new request every time event triggers. Also not sending any data

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there aren't any other errors except `POST http://localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)`, but WP.ajax works fine in the $.ajax version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out and got the data sending. For reference the working code is below:

```
var articleFilter = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var filter = document.getElementById("filter");

    filter.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      filter.value = this.value;

      articleFilter.onload = function() {
        if (articleFilter.status === 200) {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = articleFilter.responseText;
        }
      };

      articleFilter.open("POST", WP.ajax, true);

      var formData = new FormData(filter);

      articleFilter.send(formData);
    }); // END
```